# Let $\phi$ parametrize a surface. Show that if the normal vector to the surface is constant, then the surface is contained in a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, differential-geometry, proof-writing, vectors

The set of notes from my University states the following theorem without proof:

---

**Theorem:** Let $U$ be a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a differentiable function such that

1. The rank of $D\phi(u,v)$ is $2$ for every $(u,v)\in U$, and
2. The normal vector to the surface at $(u,v)$ is constant,

then the trace $\phi(U)$ is contained in a plane.

---

I've been trying to prove it to no avail. I understand why $U$ must be connected (if the condition did not hold we could allow for a piecewise function which trace consisted of multiple slices of the same plane, each slice displaced a different amount). Yet I have trouble making use of condition $(1)$, as I don't see intuitively why it is necesssary.

---

How could the Theorem be proved?

Comment: Without the rank condition, the image may not be a surface at all, let alone a regular surface (one with a tangent plane, hence normal vector, at each point).

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

Let $x_0\in U$. Then *if* $\phi(U)$ is contained in an affine plane it has to be $\{p\in\mathbb R^3|\langle p-\phi(x_0),\nu\rangle=0\}$ where $\nu$ is the constant unit normal. Therefore for $f:U\to\mathbb R,\,f(x)=\langle \phi(x)-\phi(x_0),\nu\rangle$ you want to show $f\equiv 0$.

Now use: A differentiable function $f:U\to\mathbb R$ defined on a connected open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is constant iff $\nabla f\equiv 0$ (this can be derived e.g. from the mean value theorem).